# In react-native there is TypeError

Tags: react-native

```
'use strict';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TextInput,
    Image
} from 'react-native';

var Forecast=require('./Forecast');
const APIKEY = "API KEY";

var WeatherProject = React.createClass({
//if you want to have a default zip code, 넌 여기에 넣을 수 있다.
    getInitialState(){
        return {
            zip:'', //우편 번호
            forecast: null
        };
    },
    _handleTextChange(event){
        var zip= event.nativeEvent.text;
        this.setState({zip:zip});
        fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip='
            +zip+'.KR&units=metric&APPID='+APIKEY)
            .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJSON) => {
                    this.setState({
                        forecast: {
                            main: responseJSON.weather[0].main,
                            description: responseJSON.weather[0].description,
                            temp: responseJSON.main.temp
                        }
                    });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.warn(error);
                });
    },
    render(){
        var content = null;
        if( this.state.forecast!==null){
            content = <Forecast
                main={this.state.forecast.main}
                description={this.state.forecast.description}
                temp={this.state.forecast.temp}/>;
        }
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image
                    source = {require('./img/flower.jpeg')}
                    resizeMode='cover'
                    style={styles.backdrop}>
                    <View style={styles.overlay}>
                        <View style={styles.row}>
                            <Text style={styles.mainText}>
                                Current weather for
                            </Text>
                            <View>
                                <TextInput
                                    style={styles.zipCode}
                                    returnKeyType='go'
                                    onSubmitEditing={this._handleTextChange}/>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                            {content}
                    </View>
                </Image>
            </View>
        );
    }
});

var baseFontSize = 16;
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        paddingTop:5
    },
    backdrop: {
        flex:1,
        flexDirection:'column'
    },
    overlay:{
        paddingTop:5,
        backgroundColor:'#000000',
        opacity:0.5,
        flexDirection:'column',
        alignItems:'center'
    },
    row:{
        flex:1,
        flexDirection:'row',
        flexWrap:'nowrap',
        alignItems:'flex-start',
        padding:30
    },
    zipCode:{
        width:70,
        height:30,
        marginLeft:5,
        backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF',
        fontSize:20,
        padding:0,
        color: '#000000'
    },
    mainText:{
        flex:1,
        fontSize:baseFontSize,
        color:'#FFFFFF'
    }
});

module.exports=WeatherProject;
```

In _handleTextChange(event) function

```
.then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJSON) => {
                    this.setState({
                        forecast: {
                            main: responseJSON.weather[0].main,
                            description: responseJSON.weather[0].description,
                            temp: responseJSON.main.temp
                        }
                    });
            })
```

in this code, TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'responseJSON.weather[0]') There is an error.. why this error occuered?
How can I exchange this code to execute normally?

Comment: What does `responseJSON` look like?

Comment: none.. that code is all

Comment: I mean: what are the contents of `responseJSON`? Does it actually have a `weather` array that has at least one item?

Comment: sorry.. I copy that code from other's blog , so that code is all.. also I don't know why there is responseJSON and weather array ...

Comment: It's going to be really difficult for others to help you if you can't even assist in debugging your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is occurring because you have left out a valid API key to query against the OpenWeatherMap API. The response that comes back for what you have written is:

`{"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}`

Following this link will explain the requirement to set up an account and create an API key to use this service.

I created an account and API key with OpenWeatherMap, used your code sample, popping in a simple stateless component to dump out the props passed in to the `Forecast` component to verify this is all you need to correct your error.